# MongoDB match words in array

Tags: json, mongodb

I need help to resovled my issue, i want to filter out a match in my product.

**My JSON dump**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("568ff9d4d857b6850692e589"),
    "UUID" : "b80b780d-be21-40f9-aee6-b321b663cb76",
    "CNETID" : "S12785103",
    "Url" : "intel-xeon-e5-2620v2-2-1-ghz-processor-6-kerner-15-mb-cache",
    "LastChanged" : "2016-01-22 09:04:34",
    "Manufacturer" : {
        "UUID" : "d6e0233f-2ba1-11e5-a2ac-0050569068de",
        "Title" : "Lenovo",
        "Url" : "lenovo",
        "SKU" : "00FE669",
        "EAN" : "0883436496476"
    },
    "Store" : {
        "Title" : "Intel Xeon E5-2620V2 - 2.1 GHz Processor - 6 kerner - 15 mb cache",
        "Description" : "",
        "Price" : "572200",
        "PriceDiscount" : "0",
        "AllowDisplay" : "1",
        "Activated" : "1",
        "LastSynced" : "2016-01-21 17:22:48"
    },
    "Category" : [ 
        "b085ebc3-0f0f-48c8-817f-fae04093d092"
    ],
    "PhotoCDN" : [],
    "Specifications" : {
        "Small" : [ 
            {
                "Header" : "Produktbeskrivelse",
                "Body" : "Intel Xeon E5-2620V2 / 2.1 GHz Processor"
            }, 
            {
                "Header" : "Produkttype",
                "Body" : "Processor"
            }, 
            {
                "Header" : "Processortype",
                "Body" : "Intel Xeon E5-2620V2"
            }, 
            {
                "Header" : "Antal kerner",
                "Body" : "6 kerner"
            }, 
            {
                "Header" : "Cache",
                "Body" : "15 MB"
            }, 
            {
                "Header" : "Antal processorer",
                "Body" : "1"
            }, 
            {
                "Header" : "Clock-frekvens",
                "Body" : "2.1 GHz"
            }, 
            {
                "Header" : "Max Turbo Speed",
                "Body" : "2.6 GHz"
            }, 
            {
                "Header" : "Bushastighed",
                "Body" : "1600 MHz"
            }, 
            {
                "Header" : "Producentgaranti",
                "Body" : "1-års garanti"
            }, 
            {
                "Header" : "Designet for",
                "Body" : "System x3550 M4"
            }
        ],
        "Full" : [ 
            {
                "Header" : "Produkttype",
                "Body" : "Processor"
            }, 
            {
                "Header" : "Type / Model",
                "Body" : "Intel Xeon E5-2620V2"
            }, 
            {
                "Header" : "Antal kerner",
                "Body" : "6 kerner"
            }, 
            {
                "Header" : "Cache",
                "Body" : "15 MB"
            }, 
            {
                "Header" : "Detaljer for cache-hukommelse",
                "Body" : "- 15 MB"
            }, 
            {
                "Header" : "Antal processorer",
                "Body" : "1"
            }, 
            {
                "Header" : "Clock-frekvens",
                "Body" : "2.1 GHz"
            }, 
            {
                "Header" : "Max Turbo Speed",
                "Body" : "2.6 GHz"
            }, 
            {
                "Header" : "Bushastighed",
                "Body" : "1600 MHz"
            }, 
            {
                "Header" : "Termisk designstrøm",
                "Body" : "80 W"
            }, 
            {
                "Header" : "Installeret størrelse",
                "Body" : "15 MB"
            }, 
            {
                "Header" : "Service & Support",
                "Body" : "1-års garanti"
            }, 
            {
                "Header" : "Detaljer om service & support",
                "Body" : "Begrænset garanti - 1 år"
            }, 
            {
                "Header" : "Designet for",
                "Body" : "Lenovo System x3550 M4"
            }
        ],
        "Search" : {
            "T0000002" : "Processor",
            "T0000162" : "Intel Xeon E5-2620V2",
            "T0003956" : "6 kerner",
            "T0001106" : "15 MB",
            "T0003943" : "- 15 MB",
            "T0000163" : "1",
            "T0000164" : "2.1 GHz",
            "T0003412" : "2.6 GHz",
            "T0000366" : "1600 MHz",
            "T0005726" : "80 W",
            "T0000110" : "15 MB",
            "T0000025" : "1-års garanti",
            "T0000026" : "Begrænset garanti - 1 år",
            "T0003807" : "Lenovo System x3550 M4"
        }
    }
}
```

And what i want is find a keyword inside my json tree

```
Specifications -> Full -> Array[Body]
```

And after it i need to index on this feild to if its possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very good description how to search in documents with arrays:

https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/query-documents/#arrays

e.g. to find all documents with Prodkuttype=Processor:

```
db.cat.find({
  "Specifications.Full":{
    $elemMatch:{
      Header: "Produkttype", Body: "Processor"
}}})
```